# Converting mixed type return data from an unmanaged C DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, wrapper, dllimport

I am writing a wrapper C# DLL to interface with a supplier provided unmanaged DLL written in C. For the most part everything is smooth, however there are some functions that in the provided documentation look like this:

```
int get_value(int unit, int id, int* value)
```

My issue is that `int* value` is an array with a mixture of int's and float's... The documentation states which is which, i.e. that the first value is an `int`, the second and third are `float`, etc.. I have some success if i specifically call out the DLL `value` as `int` or `float`. That returns some of the data i'm looking for, but only for the one type. For example, this kinda works:

```
[DllImport("supplier.dll")]
public static extern int get_value(int unit, int id, float* value)

public static int GetValue(int unit, int id, out float[] value)
{
     float[] value = new float[3];
     int ret = get_value(unit, id, value);
     
     return ret;
}
```

`value` is returned with [NaN, value1, value2] because the 0 index is actually an integer and it's not interpreted correctly. I have attempted to use an IntPtr[] as the return `value` in the unmanaged DLL and then use `Marshal.Copy()` to get the data from the memory locations, but this hasn't gone well. Is that a promising approach? If so, I'm not sure which overload to use, an example would be very helpful!

Comment: You can create something that acts somewhat like a C `union` by creating a `struct` with `LayoutKind.Explicit` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind).  Work with an array of those, maybe??

Comment: Either go down the explicit struct route, or use just `IntPtr` (and do pointer math) not `IntPtr[]`. I must say, this is why I hate C, this should have been declared as either a `struct*` or a `void*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `int* value` is an array with a mixture of int's and float's...

That's a serious violation of the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/995714) and will **invoke undefined behavior**. In C you'll have to use a union instead. The documentation should be like this

```c
union Value
{
    int i;
    float f;
};

int get_value(int unit, int id, union Value* value);
```

Disregarding the original UB in supplier.dll C# you can simulate the similar feature with `FieldOffset`

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] 
public struct Value
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int i;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public float f;
}

[DllImport("supplier.dll")]
public static extern int get_value(int unit, int id, out Value[] value);

public static int GetValue(int unit, int id, out Value[] value)
{
     float[] value = new float[3];
     int ret = get_value(unit, id, value);
     
     return ret;
}
```

After obtaining the array, just use the correct field to get the expected value

```cs
var ret = GetValue(unit, id, out Value[] value);
var f0 = value[0].f;
var i1 = value[1].i;
```

---

If you really want to do that without a union then you must get the float's binary representation like this

```cs
float f0 = value[0];
int i1 = BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(value[1]);
int i2 = BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(value[2]);

value[1] = BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle(f0 + 0.123f);
```

---

But if the array always has 3 items like that then why return an array instead of a struct?

```cs
public struct Values
{
    public float f0;
    public int i1;
    public int i2;
}

[DllImport("supplier.dll")]
public static extern int get_value(int unit, int id, out Values values);

public static int GetValue(int unit, int id, out Values values) {...}
```

Comment: Great answer. The BitConverter method works, but the struct is much more elegant. Thank you!